Socket emit with promise
I need to send a file to the server using a socket and measure the sending speed. I'm trying to do this by wrapping the emit in a promise.
const emit = (event, data) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (!socket) {
    reject("No socket connection.");
  } else {
    socket.emit(event, data, (response) => {
      if (response.error) {
        console.error(response.error);
        reject(response.error);
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }
});

};
then i call it as a promise, i need to know for sure that the file has been sent, but console.log("resolved") does not work.
const startTimeUpload = dayjs();

emit("message", dataJson).then(() => {
  console.log("resolved");
  const endTimeUpload = dayjs();
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
})

